# Data not stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble finding the error here. I'm receiving data through the following *html form*:

```
<form action="insertpacient.php" method="POST">
    <br> Prenume:
    <br>
    <textarea name="firstname" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <br> Nume:

    <br>
    <textarea name="lastname" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <br> Sex:

    <br>
    <select name="sex" size="1" required>
        <option value="" selected hidden>Selectați o variantă</option>
        <option value="Feminin">Feminin</option>
        <option value="Masculin">Masculin</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br> CNP:

    <br>
    <textarea name="cnp" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <br> Număr de telefon:
    <br>
    <textarea name="phonenumber" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <br> E-mail:

    <br>
    <textarea name="email" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <br> Adresă:

    <br>
    <textarea name="address" style="height:100px;" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <br> Discount:

    <br>
    <select name="producername" size="1" required>
        <option value="" selected hidden>Selectați o variantă</option>
        <option value="5">5%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="15">15%</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input style="width:40%;background-color:#F4FDFE;border-radius: 5px; border:2px outset #FFFFFF; height:24px" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this is the *insertpacient.php* file:

```
<?php
$firstname   = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname    = $_POST['lastname'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$cnp         = $_POST['cnp'];
$address     = $_POST['address'];
$email       = $_POST['email'];
$discount    = $_POST['discount'];
$sex         = $_POST['sex'];

if (!empty($firstname) || !empty($lastname) || $sex == 'Selectați o variantă' || $discount == 'Selectați o variantă' || !empty($phonenumber) || !empty($cnp) || !empty($address) || !empty($email)) {
    $host       = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname     = "pharmagest";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect Error(' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        $SELECT = "SELECT lastname From pacients Where lastname = ? Limit 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT Into pacients (firstname,lastname,phonenumber,cnp,address,email,discount,sex) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $lastname);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($lastname);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($rnum == 0) {
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssddssds", $firstname, $lastname, $phonenumber, $cnp, $address, $email, $discount, $sex);
            $stmt->execute();
            header("Location: insertpacientconfirmationpage.php");
        } else {
            echo "NAH";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
} else {
    echo 'ERROR';
    die();
}
?>
```

It does go to the confirmation page, but data is not stored in the database, for some reason.

I have to mention i have used the very same code for gathering data for another table, but I had to change some input types.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I only have one table though

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** You're sending the discount (`$_POST['discount']`) with the name `producername`. So, it should be `$_POST['producername']`.

**Problem 2:** Your first query is unnecessary since you can make the `lastname` unique or some other columns like `email` or `phonenumber`.

**Problem 3:** You should be using `&&` instead of `||` in your `if` statement. Or you can refactor nested `if` statements (arrow type code).

```
<?php

$firstname   = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname    = $_POST['lastname'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$cnp         = $_POST['cnp'];
$address     = $_POST['address'];
$email       = $_POST['email'];
$discount    = $_POST['producername'];
$sex         = $_POST['sex'];

if (empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || $sex == 'Selectați o variantă' || $discount == 'Selectați o variantă' || empty($phonenumber) || empty($cnp) || empty($address) || empty($email)) {
    die('Error');
}

$host       = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbname     = 'test';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error(' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$INSERT = 'INSERT INTO pacients (firstname, lastname, phonenumber, cnp, address, email, discount, sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);

if ($stmt->bind_param("ssddssds", $firstname, $lastname, $phonenumber, $cnp, $address, $email, $discount, $sex) && $stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    header('Location: insertpacientconfirmationpage.php');
}
```

Comment: Now I'm receiving these:

Notice: Undefined index: discount in C:\xampp\htdocs\PharmaGest\insertpacient.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\PharmaGest\insertpacient.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PharmaGest\insertpacient.php on line 31

Comment: It should be `$discount    = $_POST['producername'];` on line 9.